# regular expression with letters, numbers and some punctuation

Tags: java, regex

I am very new to regular expressions.  I need to construct a regular expression which if used in the code below would produce a newLine that had only letters (upper and lowercase), numbers, `@`, `-`, `_` and `.`.

The following expression does not work: `([^\\w][^@][^-][^_][^\\.])`.  It replaces some of the letters and not all of the unwanted characters. Why doesn't it work?

```
String line = in.nextLine();
String newLine = line.replaceAll( "([^\\w][^@][^-][^_][^\\.])", " ");
```

Comment: You can use `[^-\w@.]` regex, should be escaped for Java, so `[^-\\w@.]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@.]",""));
```